# How is it possible that I can checkout a non-existant branch in Git?

Tags: git, git-branch

There is a lot I don't know about Git.  I hope to learn how this can happen:

- 2 month ago I had an active branch: feature/branch-1
- The branch was merged into my default branch: develop
- It was removed in the remote repository (bit-bucket)
- It was removed from the local file system: `git branch -d feature/branch-1`
- `git branch` I don't seen the branch
- Today I was surprised to find that I could do: `git checkout feature/branch-1`
- `git branch` I can see the branch

Is git finding out the merge point (when the branch was merged) and checking out that commit?

Comment: Are you sure the branch was deleted in all the remotes? Check with `git branch -vav`.

Comment: You haven't done ` git fetch -p` so the remote tracking branch still exists in your local repo, and that's what was checked out. (Or more accurately, a local branch was created based on the tracking branch.)

Comment: I had never used prune before.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `git checkout` and `git switch` (which in this case do the same thing) have built into them a special feature.  The way they handle the request to switch to a string that resembles a branch name name is this:

1. Check to see if the given string, e.g., `foo` or `feature/branch-1` or `5a73c`, already exists *as* a branch name.  If so, that's the name of the branch to check out.
2. Check to see if the given string, e.g., `5a73c`, can be turned into a *valid hash ID for a commit*.  If so, that's the *commit* to check out, as a detached HEAD.  (Here `git checkout` will just do that, and `git switch` will die with a fatal error unless you used `--detach`, in which case it's fine and will just do that too.)
3. Assuming we've gotten this far, if `--guess` is in effect (see below), use the guessing code.  In older versions of Git this is called "DWIM mode", where DWIM stands for Do What I Mean.  ([DWIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWIM) has a long history going back to Lisp in the 1960s, even before I used computers: I didn't start messing with hardware and then software until the 1970s.)

The `--guess` option first became formal (and properly documented) in [<sub><sup>commit `ccb111b342f472d12baddbfa5b5281`</sup></sub>](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ccb111b342f472d12baddbfa5b52810da1725ffd), first released in Git 2.23.0, but since it defaults to *on* and was always there before that, is on unless you explicitly turn it off, which requires a Git version of at least 2.23.  So it's almost always on.

The way it works is to scan each of the *remote-tracking names* in your own repository.  These names are created and updated at `git fetch` time, including most of the `git fetch` operations run by `git pull` operations.  They are, by default, *not deleted* unless you explicitly run `git fetch --prune` or `git remote prune`, or for the special case when you specifically use `git push` to delete a branch from a remote for which you currently have a corresponding remote-tracking name.

Your remote-tracking names are the names that resemble, e.g., `origin/foo` or `origin/feature/branch-1`.  You're unlikely to have an `origin/5a73c` since nobody would use that as a branch name: your remote-tracking names are your Git's copies of someone else's branch names, and the someone else would be crazy<sup>1</sup> to use that as a branch name.  But it can happen by accident with an occasional four or more letter word<sup>2</sup> that's made up entirely of valid hexadecimal digits: branch names such as `deed` or `efface` or `faded` can trigger weirdness here.

In any case, assuming we get into step 3—the `--guess` code—in the first place, Git scans your remote-tracking names.  You typed in, e.g.:

```
git checkout feature/branch-1
```

when you have no `feature/branch-1` branch, so step 1 failed; `feature/branch-1` cannot be turned into a valid hash ID because it contains non-hexadecimal characters such as `t` and the forward slash; and so we reach step 3.  Git now scans all your `origin/*` names: is one of them `origin/feature/branch-1`?

In this case: yes, one is.  Git will also scan all *other* remote-tracking names, such as `upstream/*`, at this point, to find *all* candidates.  The list of all such candidates then enters one last set of tests:

- Is the list empty?  If so, the guessing fails.
- Is the list exactly one element long?  If so, that's the remote-tracking name you want Git to guess.
- Otherwise (more than one entry in the list), the guessing fails due to the contest between the matches, *unless* you use a feature introduced in Git 2.19), `checkout.defaultRemote`.  This feature lets you pick a particular remote that "wins" such contests.

In this case, you got exactly one match: `origin/feature/branch-1`.  That enabled `--guess` to guess that rather than:

```
git checkout feature/branch-1
```

you meant:

```
git checkout -b feature/branch-1 --track origin/feature/branch-1
```

and so that's what `git checkout` did.  (While `git switch` spells this with `-c`, `git switch` behaves the same way here, using the same control knobs: `--guess` on the command line and `checkout.defaultRemote` for handling ambiguous multiple matches.)

One potential lesson here is that it may be wise to run `git fetch -p` or `git remote prune` often, or even set `fetch.prune` to `true` in your personal Git configuration.  Otherwise you can have a lot of stale remote-tracking names, and with people being people, names you invent for *your* new feature might collide with some old name someone invented for *their* new feature.  Or, instead of that lesson, perhaps the one to take is to disable guessing (with the new-in-Git-2.30 `config.guess` setting, perhaps).  Note that if you want to use remote-tracking name `origin/foo` to create local branch `foo`, you can type in:

```
git switch -t origin/foo
```

(the `-c foo` part is implied).  This works with the old `git checkout` too, of course.

---

<sup>1</sup>There may be a method to their madness, or perhaps just a madness to their method.

<sup>2</sup>The shortest abbreviation Git will allow for a raw hash ID is four characters.  Hence the branch name `abc`, despite being made up of hexadecimal digits, is never a commit hash ID.  But `abcd` *is* sometimes a commit hash ID.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to provide a detailed step-by-step description of what is happening.  As a follow up I executed `git remote show origin` and indeed I do see `refs/remotes/origin/feature/branch-1 stale (use 'git remote prune' to remove)`!  I am just learning about prune...and a few other things you mentioned that I need to read up on...